# Rotating Right and Left using dynamic linked list

Tags: c#, rotation, shift, doubly-linked-list

I need to shift bits left and right and ive done this so far.
using a linked list

```
    public static uint RotateLeft(this uint value, int count)
    {
        return (value << count) | (value >> (32 - count));
    }

    public static uint RotateRight(this uint value, int count)
    {
        return (value >> count) | (value << (32 - count));
    }
```

But i need to use a circular dynamic linked list with eight elements, each of which may contain a bit and put together so it reperesent exactly fills one byte.  I need to rotate from 1-8 , please any suggestsion?

A requirement is that the program will use a circular dynamic linked list with eight elements, each of which may contain a bit and put together so represent an integer thus exactly fills a byte. To be able to be rotated from 1 to 8 bits.

Comment: Is this an assignment? Because using a linked list is a really inefficient way to implement rotate. Also, I don't get how your displayed code has anything to do with a linked list.

Comment: My code has nothing to do with a linked list, but i need to know how to  make a cirkular linked list and then using it with shifting

Comment: A circular linked list is like a regular linked list, but the head points to the tail and vice versa. So, with that structure, rotating simply becomes walking the list the number of bits you're shifting, and then walking the whole list from there to get the result.